# Global Mapper - .SP1 conversion to Shapefile

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-10.1

Does anyone know how to convert an .SP1 file to an shapefile from Global Mapper to ArcView 10.1?  The .SP1 is a GPX file.

Answer (score 1):

I used ExpertGPS to do the conversion. Thanks